# Custom loss for "weighted" rmse

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing a regression with Keras/TF
The values to be predicted can range from -1 to 1.
In my use case, error on sign are a big problem, so I want to predict:

- Correct value
- But above, correct sign

For example if I have to predict +0.01, predicting +0.1 is less a problem than predicting -0.01. 
Same if I have to predict -0.01, predicting -0.1 is less a problem than predicting +0.01

I though I will use a custom loss to punish more error sign.
So from a rmse like function, I have added coefficient to sign errors like this:

```
def loss_rmse2(y_true, y_pred):
    z = K.zeros_like(y_true)
    tp = K.switch( tf.logical_and( K.greater(y_true, z), K.greater(y_pred, z)) , K.square(y_true-y_pred), z)
    fp = K.switch( tf.logical_and( K.less(y_true, z), K.greater(y_pred, z)) , K.square(y_true-y_pred), z)
    tn = K.switch( tf.logical_and( K.less(y_true, z), K.less(y_pred, z)) , K.square(y_true-y_pred), z)
    fn = K.switch( tf.logical_and( K.greater(y_true, z), K.less(y_pred, z)) , K.square(y_true-y_pred), z)
    return K.sqrt(K.mean(tp) + 2 * K.mean(fp) + K.mean(tn) + 2 * K.mean(fn) )
```

The problem is that my model does not converge to a solution.

Any idea how to handle that?

Thanks

Loss function:
[image: Loss]

Comment: Is the model diverging?  Any more details?  Any code we can run?

Comment: I've added the loss evolution. 
I'm using the whole data per batch. (batch size = len(data))

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing binary classification, I would recommend normalizing to between 0 and 1 (add 1, then divide by 2), and then using `keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)`

Comment: Thing is I'm doing regression but the sign of the output can be interpreted as a classification. But I need both the sign and the value...